# enable compression between haproxy and trafficserver

Tags: haproxy, apache-traffic-server

I have proxies (trafficserver) around the world that are behind haproxy server.
Can I compress the traffic between haproxy and the trafficserver to save bandwidth?

Thanks
Yossi

Comment: They are *behind* HAProxy?  That is to say, an HAProxy `backend` is what accesses them?

Comment: they are used inside haproxy backend block